# php insert each element of array in mysql if strlen of the element is more than

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Input form with 2 fields.

```
Value of one field is 11
The second field is blank.
Field names are `date_day[]`
```

Here is my code:

```
foreach ($_POST['date_day'] as $i => $date_day) {
$strlen = (strlen($date_day));
echo $strlen .' strlen<br>';
}
```

But I get this:

```
2 strlen
0 strlen
```

Based on above I expect that code will insert into mysql only array element which strlen is more than 0

Here is my code for insert:

```
if ( (strlen($date_day)) > 0 ) {
$sql .= implode(', ', $insertQuery) . 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE RecordDay = VALUES(RecordDay);';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($insertData);
}
```

However if string length in one of fields is more than 0 and in other field string length is 0, code inserts both fields (the second field empty).

I need to insert only field which string length is more than 0. If 0 do not insert at all.... where is mistake (what need to change in code)?

Comment: If(isset($var_name)) && isset($var_name{1}){

//rest of ur code
}

Comment: With isset executes (inserts) also if no value entered

Answer (score 0):

chnage this code

```
if ( (strlen($date_day)) > 0 ) {
$sql .= implode(', ', $insertQuery) . 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE RecordDay = VALUES(RecordDay);';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($insertData);
}
```

To

```
if ( (strlen(trim($date_day))) > 0 ) {
$sql .= implode(', ', $insertQuery) . 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE RecordDay = VALUES(RecordDay);';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($insertData);
}
```

Comment: hmm, with if ( (strlen(trim($date_day))) > 0 ) { is the same behavior.  Inserts empty value...

Comment: okay now change the condition check to this if($date_day != "")

Comment: the same is with $_POST['date_day'][$i]

Comment: try this if(!empty($date_day))

Comment: The same. Inserts empty value